# how can i get a result diferent to 0 and 1 clasification, keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have my model  and when I predict my image I get a a result like this
I know that this is the clasificatory, but I need a "percentage" that this result
[0 , 0 , 0 , 1]

and I need something like this

[.04, .1, .94, .07]
and when I use argmax I have de result [3]
but I can't
I have tried with predict(), predict_proba() and predict_classes() but didn't work 
my training code is:

```
data_entrenamiento = './data/entrenamiento'
data_validacion = './data/validacion'

epocas=20
longitud, altura = 150, 150
batch_size = 32
pasos = 200
validation_steps = 50
filtrosConv1 = 32
filtrosConv2 = 64
tamano_filtro1 = (3, 3)
tamano_filtro2 = (2, 2)
tamano_pool = (2, 2)
clases = 3
lr = 0.0004

entrenamiento_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rescale=1. / 255,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

entrenamiento_generador = entrenamiento_datagen.flow_from_directory(
data_entrenamiento,
target_size=(altura, longitud),
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='categorical')

validacion_generador = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
data_validacion,
target_size=(altura, longitud),
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='categorical')

cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv1, tamano_filtro1, padding ="same",         input_shape=(longitud, altura, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=tamano_pool))

cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv2, tamano_filtro2, padding ="same"))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=tamano_pool))

cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(Dense(clases, activation='softmax'))

cnn.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy ',
        optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=lr),
        metrics=['accuracy'])

callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2),



cnn.fit_generator(
entrenamiento_generador,
steps_per_epoch=pasos,
epochs=epocas,
callbacks=callbacks,
validation_data=validacion_generador,
validation_steps=validation_steps)
```

and my classification code is:

```
def predict(file):
x = load_img(file, target_size=(longitud, altura))
x = img_to_array(x)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
array = cnn.predict(x,batch_size=32,verbose=1)
print(array)
result = array[0]
answer = np.argmax(result)
if answer == 0:
  print("pred: Perro")
elif answer == 1:
  print("pred: Gato")
elif answer == 2:
  print("pred: Gorila")

return answer
```

I have tried with predict(), predict_proba() and predict_classes() but didn't work

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question. What do you exactly want?

Comment: I want something like that [.04, .1, .94, .07]  and my results are only integers [0,0,0,1]